# Manipulating an Image to see the effect of changing certain properties

Tags: manipulate, interactive

I tried to create a `Manipulate` expression containing an image where I can adjust some values, `color1`, `color2`, `val1`, `val2` and `num` to see the effect changing them have on the image.

My code for processing the image with fixed values for `color1`, `color2`, `val1`, `val2` and `num` is shown below. How can I modify it to be interactive?
color1, color2 can be chosen in colour spaces: Red,Green,Blue,Black,White etc
val1,val2 in sliders with value from 0.1-1, step 0.1
num in slider: 100-5000 stepsize 100

```
val1 = 0.4;
val2 = 0.4
num = 2000
color1 = Red
color2 = Black

img = an image
DeleteSmallComponents[
  MorphologicalComponents[
   RemoveBackground[img, {"Foreground", {color1, val1}}], num]];
im = RemoveBackground[img, {"Foreground", {color2, val2}}];
ima = EdgeDetect[im];

cen = ComponentMeasurements[
   ima, {"Centroid"}, #Holes == 1 && 
     10 < #Area && #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &];

b = Flatten[cen /. Rule -> List, 2]; (* remove arrow*)

(*sort out even and odd element, even elements contain coordinate for \
hole*)
{x, y} = Partition[b, 2, 2, 1, {}]~Flatten~{2}; 
(*y : hole centroid location*)
dm = DelaunayMesh[y];

v = MeshPrimitives[dm, 0];
t = MeshPrimitives[dm, 2];

vedg = Length[Position[Level[t, {2}], #]] & /@ Level[v, {2}];
kN = Max[vedg];
mnloc = Flatten[Position[vedg, kN]];
mntri = Flatten[
   Position[ContainsAny[#, Level[v[[mnloc]], {2}]] & /@ Level[t, {2}],
     True]];

nc = t[[mntri]];
knpic = Graphics[{Red, {PointSize[0.01], Point[y]}, Green, 
    MeshPrimitives[dm, 1], {Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[Red], 
     EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], nc, FaceForm[Yellow]}}];
Show[img, knpic, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you want to `Manipulate` your colours? With named colours, like `Red` as you're doing, or with sliders (in which case you'll probably want to specify a colour space). Would `val1` and `val2` would be controlled by sliders, between 0 and 1? Also, you might want to include a sample image.

Comment: val1 and val2 are controlled by sliders from 0.1 to 1 with step 0.1. Color would be Red,Green,Black Blue...etc in color space. num is from 100 to 5000, stepsize 100. The problem is I cant zip all these code into a function with variable color1,2, val1,2 and num and then apply manipulate to that function

Comment: I believe you need to provide `img[[imageno]]` in order for members to help with your question.

Comment: it's just an image in my list of images. We can use any image